# Why Spring Data JPA / Hibernate is not binding `Pageable` values to generated query?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I am using `spring-data-jpa (2.1.7.RELEASE)` with hibernate (5.6.9.Final) as ORM implementation.

I am creating `Pageable` object in service layer and passing it to repo layer -

**Service Layer Code:**

```
Pageable pg = PageRequest.of(4, 2);
Page<Tuple> packagesList = packageRepository.getPackageByAccountIdAndPackageId(accountId, packageId, pg);
```

**Repository Layer Code:**

```
public interface PackageRepository extends JpaRepository<Packages, PackageId> { ...
```

and

```
@Query(value = "SELECT p.package_id FROM packages p WHERE p.account_id=:accountId AND (CASE WHEN :packageId IS NULL THEN TRUE WHEN  p.package_id LIKE :packageId THEN TRUE ELSE FALSE END)",
            countQuery = "SELECT count(*) FROM packages", nativeQuery = true)
Page<Tuple> getPackageByAccountIdAndPackageId(String accountId, String packageId, Pageable pg);
```

---

In the generated SQL - the `limit` restriction is getting added but no binding values are getting generated. Below should clarify that -

**Query and Binding Params**

```
Hibernate: 
    SELECT
        p.package_id 
    FROM
        packages p 
    WHERE
        p.account_id=? 
        AND (
            CASE 
                WHEN ? IS NULL THEN TRUE 
                WHEN  p.package_id LIKE ? THEN TRUE 
                ELSE FALSE 
            END
        ) limit ?, ?
2022-10-15 18:43:46.285 TRACE 68021 --- [nio-8095-exec-1] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - [40955353-d2c3-4377-8c95-6b403b7570ef]
2022-10-15 18:43:46.286 TRACE 68021 --- [nio-8095-exec-1] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [2] as [VARCHAR] - [%2]
2022-10-15 18:43:46.286 TRACE 68021 --- [nio-8095-exec-1] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [3] as [VARCHAR] - [%2]
2022-10-15 18:43:46.328 TRACE 68021 --- [nio-8095-exec-1] .s.t.s.TransactionSynchronizationManager : Retrieved value [org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerHolder@41baa13] for key [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean@7317fb] bound to thread [http-nio-8095-exec-1]
2022-10-15 18:43:46.329 TRACE 68021 --- [nio-8095-exec-1] .s.t.s.TransactionSynchronizationManager : Retrieved value [org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerHolder@41baa13] for key [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean@7317fb] bound to thread [http-nio-8095-exec-1]
```

**Why binding parameters 4 and 5 corresponding to offset and limit are not getting generated even though the query is expecting them.**

Note: The query is succeeding and I am not getting any exception.
Note: plz ignore the count query. It is intentionally incorrect. I added it to see if count query makes any difference. But it did not.
**Q2 - Is count query mandatory for Pageable to work?**

Comment: Q2: yes, for native query it is (at least [documented](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.at-query.native)) mandatory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JPA handles limit and offset separately from the rest of the query.

What Spring Data does for you is:

1. Create a query object from your SQL statement.
2. Bind parameters to it (excluding the pageable)
3. Call special methods for [`limit`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/Query.html#setMaxResults-int-) and [`offset`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/Query.html#setFirstResult-int-)

So these values get some special treatment in you JPA implementation and I guess this is why they don't get printed with normal bind parameters.

Also I seem to remember that some database doesn't allow setting these as bind parameters at all.
Which might actually be the original reason for the special treatment.

Comment: Jens - the explanation seems reasonable to accept the answer. +1